# How to convert this function to AngularJS code?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

open modal function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

});

Comment: Since modal depends heavily on jQuery check out ui-bootstrap port for angular. It has an angularjs compatible modal.  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in your view.

```
<button ng-click="open()"> Open Modal </button>
```

and below code in controller to open the model when you click the button.

```
   $scope.open = function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
   }
```

Comment: There are already two anweres that provide the same information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click over button and call the function in controller

```
<button ng-click="open()"> </button>
```

and in controller,

```
$scope.function = open(){
  $("#myModal").modal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you can use `angular.element` to select and invoke the modal

```
$scope.PopMyModal = function () {
    angular.element('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
}
```

Then use `ng-click` to bind the function

```
<button ng-click="PopMyModal()">Modal</button>
```